# Office 365 Development using Visual Studio

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, office-365

Do we have to install SharePoint  locally for Office365 development using Visual Studio 2012? or, I just need an Office365 account? Is there an online tutorial for this?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to install SharePoint locally for Office 365 app development.

Following are packages you should install along with Visual Studio 2012

- Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012
- SharePoint Client Components
- Windows Identity Foundation SDK
- Windows Identity Foundation Extensions
- Workflow Tools SDK and Workflow Client SDK

Check this article for details on developing apps for SharePoint Online

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/690015/SharePoint-Online-App-Development-Part

Since most of the customization can be achieved client side I would recommend installing SharePoint Designer 2013.